# Is passing CommandParameter together with Command is good MVVM practice?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Lets say I have code sample:

```
<ListView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructCollection}"                 
   x:Name="MyListView">          
</ListView>

<Button Width="45" Height="25"
        Content="Save"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
```

This way it is very easy to retrieve all selected objects in ListView when button is clicked, but doesn't that violate MVVM principles?
Shouldn't I create specific object with IsSelectedProperty, then bind ListView ItemsSource to collection of these objects, and then on button click just loop through this collection to see on which items IsSelectedProperty is true?
Thank you!

Comment: You're passing a collection of view model items to the command in your view model. Which MVVM principle should be violated here? However, questions like this tend to be closed as *primarily opinion-based*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends and might vary by who you ask as well. Some might argue that it is not respecting MVVM because item selection aspect is not reflected in your view model.

But I think it boils down to whether the application considers `SelectedItems` to be a state that affect application behaviour and not a transient state in view to aid submitting specific items for the action.

Think that in MVVM you should be able to simulate all possible logical interactions that can happen on the view by interacting only with the VM (imagine you are writing a test against the VM skipping the view and VM should represent exactly what is the state of the view).

For example if you have a timer that would show the user a tip if they don't select anything within a specified amount of time, you can no longer assume item selection can skip the VM.